# Music21 - cannot display rests

Tags: python, music21, lilypond, transcription

I'm cutting up sections of sheet music into snippets on the beat. I'm using music21 and LilyPond to convert the output into a png. There's a very specific issue though where I get no display of a snippet only containing a rest. If the rest is being displayed with note then it shows fine.. but if the bar consists of a rest and nothing else the image is blank.  My guess would be the program doesn't know where to place the rest when there's no context to wether a bass clef - stave is being used.. but I did attempt to providing placement information to the rest through Style.absoluteY module but no joy. If anybody could provide a bit of insight that'd be cool! Cheers

```
n = note.Note("C4")

r = note.Rest()

ss = stream.Stream()


ss.append(n)

ss.append(r)

ss.show("lily")
```

When I use the above code I get an output of [image of 1/4 note and 1/4 rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNjlJ.png)

Then, when I use the below code I get an output of [blank white box, where there should be a single 1/4 rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F5rB.png)

```
r = note.Rest()

ss = stream.Stream()



ss.append(r)

ss.show("lily")
```

Comment: might be a bug with the lily package. What happens if you just use: ss.show() ?

Comment: ss.show() opens musescore 3 and shows the score

Comment: I've been trying to use ss.show("musicxml.png") which produces the png through Musescore 3.app rather than LilyPond.app but this runs into permission errors [Errno 13]

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but have you considered using the [Abjad](https://abjad.github.io/) package for engraving music with Python? Abjad is a phenomenal package for producing LilyPond scores from within Python, and is able to produce [extremely high-level scores](https://abjad.github.io/gallery-2020.html).

Comment: Lilypond support is somewhat deprecated.  The best way to get an image file is `.show('musicxml.png')`  (music21 creator)

Answer (score 2):

Lilypond interface is not so strong, so better would be to install MuseScore

```
add-apt-repository ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore3-stable
apt update
apt install musescore3

pip uninstall music21
pip install music21
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'm using music21 already but was having issues outputting a PNG (score.show('png')) without going through LillyPond interface (score.show('lily')). If I try to use this right now I get errnor 3 with permissions issues.. guess I'll play around with it and see what happens

Comment: Can you open the mscore binary at the command line? If you're on a Mac, you may need to control-click the binary and give the OS explicit permission to run it before you try to use music21 as an interface to it.